# Determining which button the user pressed

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I would like to have three buttons or images in my view, that each represent a "weapon". How can I know which button has been selected by the user, and use this information?

I thought I would use one function to collect the information about the weapon selected, its damage, etc., but I'm used to creating one function for each button in the view. I'm wondering now how to determine the difference between those buttons, depending on which one has been selected.

Comment: Thanks Josh for the edit, for now i have nothing done, i was just thinking of how to realize it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create action methods that take one argument, the sender:

```
- (IBAction)weaponPressed:(id)sender;
```

You can then check the sender against instance variables pertaining to the buttons:

```
if (sender == gunWeaponButton)
    // Do something
else if (sender == mineWeaponButton)
    // Do something
else
    // Do something else
```

Also, you can assign a tag to the buttons, which is simply an integer value:

```
gunWeaponButton.tag = 0;
```

Then you can check for the sender's tag:

```
if (sender.tag == gunWeaponButton.tag)
    // Do something
```

Comment: On iOS, you should not use 0 for a view's `tag`, since that is the default value.

Comment: I would suggest tags rather than comparing sender to instance variables, but as @JoshCaswell pointed out, don't use 0 as tag because all the buttons without a tag set will match `if (sender.tag == 0)`.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine with comparing the instance variable, but i can't find the solution for the tag : i have an error: "request for member 'tag' in something not a structure or union", at the line if (sender.tag == ... i have declared 2 buttons like that : IBOutlet UIButton *button1; and set the tags to those buttons in viewDidLoad. Any idea?

Comment: Compiler doesn't know if object of type id has tag property. In this case it does, but you must let the compiler know. you can either change `(id)sender` in method signature to `(UIButton *)sender` or cast sender to UIButton like this: `UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender; if (senderButton.tag == 1) ...`.